# Is crossing your legs bad for your posture?

Tags: posture

I suppose that this question may break down into whether it's bad when you're working at a computer and whether it's bad when you're relaxing (and more likely to be leaning back).

My impression based on the effect it has on my back posture is that it is, but I've been challenged on this. Is there any evidence on it? (I imagine that the evidence may relate to the back posture that's normally associated with crossing your legs.)

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is basic medical/health advice, and off topic for our site.

Comment: Yes, spending much time sitting with your legs crossed is very unhealthy for you spine, for the lower back especially. It may also stress your hips if you have a hip issue.